# Buddypress Toolbar/admin bar not visible

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I added a custom header(header-new.php) to the site http://parentctrhub.staging.wpengine.com for logged in users of buddypress. The code that I added in default page template is:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
get_header('new');
} 
else {
get_header();
}
```

But, now the black buddypress toolbar/admin bar has stopped showing. It is shown for logged out users (if I check the option in buddypress settings) but not for logged in users. Weirdly, now the toolbar doesn't show up even if I undo all the changes.

Comment: If the toolbar doesn't show up regardless of the header changes you've mentioned above then the header changes you've mentioned are irrelevant. You could probably remove them from the question

Comment: Toolbar was visible before I made any changes to header.So, I guess they are important to understand the context of the problem.

Comment: But you said: "Weirdly, now the toolbar doesnt show up even if I undo all the changes."

Comment: Yes, after adding the custom header it stopped showing. But, now even if I remove the custom header, it doesnt show up.

Comment: have you made any more customisations that might have had an impact?

Comment: No, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. I just added:

```
show_admin_bar( true );
```

in functions.php file and admin bar is again showing up.